# Creating multiple git branches using a bashrc sh alias

Tags: git, bash, branch, alias

I am trying to make an alias that runs multiple commands for me. Specifically, the command is supposed to create multiple git branches in multiple directories (if you know some other way to do this, that would be great.) Here is what I am doing:

```
alias branches="folder1; git checkout -b $1 ; folder2 ; git checkout -b $1; folder3; git checkout -b $1; folder4; git checkout -b $1"
```

Note that folder(n) denotes a git repo (a seperate project) and is itself an simple cd alias that I have used before so no problem with that.

The error I am getting:

```
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `;'
```

I am doing this because when I work on featureA that affects multiple projects, like a refactoring, I want to make sure that I am always in featureA branch.

Thanks.

Edit: I want to use a sh alias. Title is edited to reflect this fact.

Comment: You can't use positional parameters (`$1`) in an alias. As @Avi demonstrates, use a function.

Comment: Are you sure? I just tried an {alias test="echo $1"} and it worked fine.

Comment: @why-el: No, it did not. Since you double-quoted the string, `$1` was evaluated *before* the alias was created. Check it by running `alias test`.

Comment: No I mean if I put that alias in Bashrc, it works. Just tried it with test "string" in the terminal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you don't want an alias, but rather a shell function:

```
function branches {
    cd folder1
    git checkout -b $1
    cd folder2
    git checkout -b $1
    cd folder3
    git checkout -b $1
    cd folder4
    git checkout -b $1
}
```

Or, better yet, do it in a loop:

```
function branches {
    for folder in folder1 folder2 folder3 folder4 ; do
        cd $folder
        git checkout -b $1
    done
}
```

Comment: Perfect. This worked. Two more questions for you though :) 1. Any idea why my first attempt did not work? and 2. any Internet resources on these types of functions? I wanna learn this skill.

Comment: @why-el: 1. Probably because `folder1` isn't a shell command - you intended to `cd folder1`.

Comment: 2. The Advanced Bash Scripting Guide is good, though long. See http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/functions.html. If you are looking for shorter resources, try googling "bash functions", or similar.

Answer (score 1):

Is that a git alias or a sh alias?

If it's a git alias you will need to add a `!` at the beginning of your code (so your shell can run it).

But from what I've read what you want isn't a git alias but a shell function, that will go in each folder and checkout the said branch (not a good idea at all by the way).

Comment: I was going for a sh alias. And the simple alias that I called branch cant execute that code then?